# Is there a way of using the newly inserted rows id as a value in the rows column in MySQL in a simple way?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to use the id of a newly inserted row inside the rows own column as a value in a simple way?

Or do I need to Insert it first, then then get lastInsertId, and then update the row?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question ?

Comment: Is it possible to insert a new row and use that row's id as a value in one of the columns in the same row in a simple way instead of inserting the row first, and then getting the last id from the row, and then updating the row's column with that lastInsertId?

Comment: Your design sounds wrong, why would you want to duplicate data? This has been discussed in a different matter (2 autoincrement fields) @ http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35449/how-to-use-2-auto-increment-columns-in-mysql-phpmyadmin

Comment: I will change my design, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that, you would need to do as you suggest and update the row again.

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

I would note, however, that this is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Yes I guess it is a bad idea and I should change my design. Thanks